# Organization of business objects and code duplication

Tags: c#, architecture

I have tabs on the website: Cinema, Concerts, Clubs, Theatres, Children, Other. Each tab displays the appropriate events and schedules.
This is my object:
For Cinema:
`Film`, `Cinema`, `CinemaSchedule`
Theater:
`Performance`, `Theater`, `TheaterSchedule`
and so on.

Now consider Concert:
`Concert`, `ConcertPlace`, `ConcertPlaceSchedule`.
But this is not correct, because the concert may be in the club or in the theater (for example).
The same situation is with the clubs. There are different events take place: concerts and parties.

So, What is the best way to organize classes? Another example: we have the film "Puss in Boots". On the one hand, this film, the other is a cartoon(Children tab). Now that the film appeared in the "Movies" and "Children" need to create it twice.

Another problem, I will show on example.

```
This is my repository for `Film`:

    public class FilmRepository:BaseRepository<Film>
        {
            public FilmRepository(DatabaseContext database) : base(database)
            {
            }
                /// <summary>
                /// Loads films for specific period
                /// </summary>
                /// <param name="period"></param>
                /// <returns></returns>
                public IList<Film> GetFilmsForPeriod(PeriodEvent period)
                {
                    switch (period)
                    {
                            case PeriodEvent.All:
                            return GetAllFilms();

                            case PeriodEvent.Today:
                            return GetFilmsForToday();

                            case PeriodEvent.Tomorrow:
                            return GetFilmsForTomorrow();

                            case PeriodEvent.Week:
                            return GetFilmsForWeek();

                            case PeriodEvent.FewWeek:
                            return GetFilmsForFewWeek();

                            case PeriodEvent.Month:
                            return GetFilmsForMonth();

                            case PeriodEvent.FewMonth:
                            return GetFilmsForFewMonth();

                        default:
                            return GetFilmsForToday();
                    }
                }

            // load films for today
            private IList<Film> GetFilmsForToday()
            {
                return
                    Database.Films.Where(c => c.CinemaSchedules.Any(s =>
                       s.ShowDate.Value.Date == DateTime.Now.Date)).ToList();
            }

           //implementation another methods from above.
    }
```

And each repository has identical methods. One difference in that instead `CinemaSchedule` is `TheaterSchedule` (or `ClubSchedule`, and so on).

How to avoid this duplication?

Thanks, and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Feels like you need to model it a different way.

Perhaps you could have a `Venue` object which represents a physical location that stuff happens in (with subclasses for e.g. `Cinema`, `Theatre`), an `Event` object that represents that stuff (e.g. `Film`, `Play`) and a `Performance` which represents a join of those two models (and so will have two foreign-keys, and probably a field for time).

Answer (score 2):

Cinema, Theater and Club shold have the same parent that has IList that returns schedules for you. The same is for repository, it seems that you can have GetFilmsForPeriod changed to GetObjectsForPeriod and have it moved to BaseRepository. Both Club and Theater can have IList Concerts. Try to merge some similar properties of your objects into parents to avoid double-coding.

As Film is a class you can have it both in Movies and Children as it is reference class.

Answer (score 1):

My first idea, is that you should have an base object called Event (or something similar just brain storming here) and that one will have objects that extends it to being a Cinema Event, Concert Event and so on building upon the [OCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle).

On your second (or was it first? Too little coffee too much time) question I don't see anything wrong with having a table that connects the specified Event with several categories.